# Nginx refuses to connect

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a nodejs app set up in a droplet powered by Nginx and Express. The REST API's are working fine when running locally. Even from within the server, I can make a CURL request to the test.domain.com/api and it returns the data. But I can't get the API to work externally. When I try 
`curl -v test.domain.com/api`
I get

```
* Trying 159.65.158.66...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 159.65.158.66 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to test.domain.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to test.domain.com port 443: Connection refused
```

This error occurred with the firewall disabled on the server. Trying HTTP throws the same error, albeit with the port 80.
Trying 
`netstat -punta | grep 443` shows

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7285/nginx: master
```

I've checked to make sure that the symlinks between the sites-enabled and sites-available is correct too.

Here's the test.domain.com from sites-enabled

```
server {


    server_name test.domain.com; # managed by Certbot

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location /
        return 200 'Here I am!';{
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = test.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
}
```

And here's my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        server_tokens off;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

server { # simple reverse-proxy
    server_name  test.domain.com;# pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  0;
    text/css                   0;
    application/javascript     0;
    ~image/                    0;
}
##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


server {
    if ($host = test.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen       81;
    server_name  test.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

}
```

I've checked the error and the access logs. I don't see anything suspicious there. This is my first time setting up a server and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: [image: The error logs]
[image: The access logs]

Comment: What does the error log for nginx say?

Comment: @k0hamed I've edited the question to add the screenshots of the logs. Thank you.

Comment: Any updates on this?